# JMeter Assertion Table height of cells

Tags: jmeter

The row height of my Jmeter is so small that I cannot read whats in the cell, also it is not possible to resize the height.

see a screenshot here: https://cloud.boris.co.at/index.php/s/NG80rN7J01o3geL

Any idea to reset that setting?

Comment: Which version of JMeter are you using  ? under what OS ? Do you have a hdpi screen ? with what resolution ?

Comment: using apache 3.2 under windows 10 pro screen has 2560 x 1440 px. After 'installing' jmeter it worked.. then maybe I changed the row height. Cannot undo this.